# Assertion error on priority queue with custom class pointers

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue, comparator, a-star

I'm implementing a A* search algorithm but I keep running into problems with the priority queue. I have implemented a custom comparator for the priority queue according to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541560/stl-priority-queue-on-custom-class)

This is the relevant code:

```
class CNode;

struct CompareNode : public binary_function<CNode*, CNode*, bool> {
    bool operator()(const CNode* lhs, const CNode* rhs) const {
        return lhs->m_costFromStart+lhs->m_heuristic > rhs->m_costFromStart+rhs->m_heuristic;
    }
};


bool AStarSearch(CNode* start, CNode* end) {
    priority_queue<CNode*, vector<CNode*>, CompareNode> open;
    ...
}
```

Call stack:

```
std::_Debug_heap ...
std::pop_heap ...
std::priority_queue<CNode *,std::vector<CNode *,std::allocator<CNode *> >,CompareNode>::pop()
AStarSearch(CNode * start=0x0f9a23b8, CNode * end=0x0f9a24e8)
```

Greater then was used as I needed a min heap for this algorithm.
The implementation seems to work fine and the problem goes away when it is run in release mode but the priority queue occasionally throws "Invalid heap" assertion failures in debug mode when the priority queue is pop()ed.

I'm not familiar with binary_function in stl but the problem seems to lie with the comparator. Removing the comparator or changing the sign to less then removes the error but that would give me a max heap. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: "Assertion error" - please specify more, where's the error and what's the call stack

Comment: You've corrupted your heap. When this happens, the place you see the error might tell you very little about the root of the error. Try to go over all your memory writes, and possibly add asserts of your own. If you don't have a lot of code, you can post it here. Otherwise, it's almost impossible to guess the root of the error. Also, note that heap corruption are sensitive to changes - changing to max heap probably doesn't fix the problem, but it hides it for you current code. Try to solve the problem without making further changes - being able to reproduce the problem is half way to solution.

Comment: An important detail to note is that in A* (or Dijkstra's) you end up changing the priorities of elements that are already in the heap.  The `std::priority_queue` class does not work well with this; if you change an element's priority, the priority queue does not automatically update to fix it; you have to do this yourself.  This may account for the behavior you're seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the help. Turns out I did not rebuild the heap after changing the cost of nodes in the priority queue. Calling

```
make_heap(const_cast<CNode**>(&open.top()), const_cast<CNode**>(&open.top()) + open.size(), 
CompareNode());
```

after every modification to the pq solved the problem.