# Priority queue for user-defined types

Tags: c++, priority-queue, min-heap

I have the below struct:

```cpp
struct node {
   float val;
   int count;
}
```

I have several objects of this struct. Now, I want to insert these objects into a priority queue of STL such that the priority queue orders the items by count. Any idea on how to do so? Preferably a min-heap is preferred. I know how to do the above for primitive data types, not structs

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Overload the < operator:

```
bool operator<(const node& a, const node& b) {
  return a.count > b.count;
}
```

I have reversed the comparison to achieve min heap without passing extra arguments to the priority queue.
Now you use it like this:

```
priority_queue<node> pq;
...
```

Edit: take a look at this post which seems to be almost exact duplicate: [STL Priority Queue on custom class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541560/stl-priority-queue-on-custom-class)

Comment: what if i push pointers in my queue. that is node*. does this change. Can you explain why do you have to override the < operator and how this workds

Comment: The priority queue is a templated class(let's say it's `template<class T> priority_queue`). Internally it uses the < operator for comparison of the elements pushed in it. So if you have not defined this operator for the class you are pushing in a priority_queue you will get an compilation error. For the question about pointers take a look at the edit of my comment.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return a.count < b.count;`?

Comment: @425nesp see in my answer: `I have reversed the comparison to achieve min heap wihtout passing extra arguments to the priority queue.`

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Operator should never be overload in such reversed way. `Define overloaded operators only if their meaning is obvious, unsurprising, and consistent with the corresponding built-in operators.` - from Google C++ style guide.

Answer (score 14):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class Boxer{
    public:
        string name;
        int strength;
};
struct Comp{
    bool operator()(const Boxer& a, const Boxer& b){
        return a.strength<b.strength;
    }
};
int main(){
    Boxer boxer[3];
    boxer[0].name="uday", boxer[0].strength=23;
    boxer[1].name="manoj", boxer[1].strength=33;
    boxer[2].name="rajiv", boxer[2].strength=53;

    priority_queue< Boxer, vector<Boxer>, Comp> pq;
    pq.push(boxer[0]);
    pq.push(boxer[1]);
    pq.push(boxer[2]);
    Boxer b = pq.top();
    cout<<b.name;
    //result is Rajiv

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This is really useful to get the complete picture.

Comment: why pass vector<Boxer>? and why are you passing a struct instead of a function? and why are you overriding the () operator instead of <?
and @mohit , I wouldn't call it a good answer if it has no explanation, especially if it's asked by a person who is obviously new to c++

Comment: Hi! I don't understand why do we need to provide the second argument, "vector<Boxer>", I mean wouldn't it work even without that?

Answer (score 11):

1. Using `greater` as comparison function you can use priority queue as min heap,

   ```
   #include <bits/stdc++.h>

   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
       priority_queue<int,vector<int>,greater<int> >pq;
       pq.push(1);
       pq.push(2);
       pq.push(3);

       while(!pq.empty())
       {
           int r = pq.top();
           pq.pop();
           cout << r << " ";
       }
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. Inserting value by changing their sign (using minus (-) for positive number and using plus (+) for negative number we can use priority queue in reversed order.

   ```
   int main()
   {
       priority_queue<int>pq2;
       pq2.push(-1); //for +1
       pq2.push(-2); //for +2
       pq2.push(-3); //for +3
       pq2.push(4);  //for -4

       while(!pq2.empty())
       {
           int r = pq2.top();
           pq2.pop();
           cout << -r << " ";
       }

       return 0;
   }
   ```
3. For custom data types or classes we need a to tell priority queue a way of knowing on which order it will sort our data.

   ```
   struct compare
   {
       bool operator()(const int & a, const int & b)
       {
           return a>b;
       }
   };

   int main()
   {

       priority_queue<int,vector<int>,compare> pq;
       pq.push(1);
       pq.push(2);
       pq.push(3);

       while(!pq.empty())
       {
           int r = pq.top();
           pq.pop();
           cout << r << " ";
       }

       return 0;
   }
   ```
4. For custom structure or class you can use `priority_queue` in any order. Suppose, we want to sort people in descending order according to their salary and if tie then according to their age.

   ```
   struct people
   {
       int age,salary;
   };
   struct compare {
       bool operator()(const people & a, const people & b)
       {
           if(a.salary==b.salary)
           {
               return a.age>b.age;
           } else {
               return a.salary>b.salary;
           }
       }
   };

   int main()
   {
       priority_queue<people,vector<people>,compare> pq;
       people person1,person2,person3;
       person1.salary=100;
       person1.age = 50;
       person2.salary=80;
       person2.age = 40;
       person3.salary = 100;
       person3.age=40;

       pq.push(person1);
       pq.push(person2);
       pq.push(person3);

       while(!pq.empty())
       {
           people r = pq.top();
           pq.pop();
           cout << r.salary << " " << r.age << endl;
       }
   ```
5. Same result can be obtained by operator overloading :

   ```
   struct people
   {
       int age,salary;

       bool operator< (const people & p) const
       {
           if(salary==p.salary)
           {
               return age>p.age;
           } else {
               return salary>p.salary;
           }
       }
   };
   ```

In main function :

```
    priority_queue<people> pq;
    people person1,person2,person3;
    person1.salary=100;
    person1.age = 50;
    person2.salary=80;
    person2.age = 40;
    person3.salary = 100;
    person3.age=40;

    pq.push(person1);
    pq.push(person2);
    pq.push(person3);

    while(!pq.empty())
    {
        people r = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        cout << r.salary << " " << r.age << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide `operator<` for that struct. Something like:

```
bool operator<(node const& x, node const& y) {
    return x.count < y.count;
}
```

Now you can use a priority queue from the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++11, you can write

```
auto comparer = [](const auto& a, const auto& b) {
    return a.priority < b.priority;
};
std::priority_queue<Item, std::vector<Item>, decltype(comparer)> queue(comparer);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can define user defined comparator class:

### Code Snippet :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct man
{
  string name;
  int priority; 
};

class comparator
{
 public:
   bool operator()(const man& a, const man& b)
   {
        return a.priority<b.priority;
   }
};

int main()
{
   man arr[5];
   priority_queue<man, vector<man>, comparator> pq;

   for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
   {
     cin>>arr[i].name>>arr[i].priority;
     pq.push(arr[i]);
   }

   while (!pq.empty())
   {
     cout<<pq.top().name<<" "<<pq.top().priority;
     pq.pop();
     cout<<endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Person
{
    public:
        string name;
        int age;
        
        Person(string str,int num)
        {
            name = str;
            age  = num;
        }
};

// FUNCTOR
class compare
{
    public:
        bool operator()(Person a,Person b)
        {
            cout << "Comparing " << a.age << " with " <<    b.age << endl;
            return a.age < b.age;
        }
};

int main() 
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    
    priority_queue <Person, vector<Person> , compare> pq;
    
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        string name;
        int x;
        
        cin >> name;
        cin >> x; 
        
        Person p(name,x);
        pq.push(p);
    }
    
    int k = 3;
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        Person p = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        cout << p.name << " " << p.age << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Operator() is also commonly overloaded to implement functors or function object. For example we have a structure Person which have some default ways of searching and sorting a person by age but we want our customized ways with some other parameter like weight so we may use our own custom functor. Priority queue is one such container which accepts a functor so it knows how to sort the objects of custom data types. Each time a comparison has to be done, a object is instantiated of class compare, and it is passed two objects of person class for comparison.