# Comparator for boost::heap::priority_queue vs std::priority_queue

Tags: c++, boost, std

I'm trying to set up a priority queue for a custom Edge class where the Edges will be compared by their weights.

```
class Edge 
{
public:
    int index;
    double weight;
std::pair<int, int> vertices;

Edge(int i, double w, int start, int end)
{
    index = i;
    weight = w;
    vertices.first = start;
    vertices.second = end;
}
};
```

I successfully implemented a `std::priority_queue` using [STL Priority Queue on custom class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541560/stl-priority-queue-on-custom-class) and http://gigi.nullneuron.net/comp/cpp-stl-priority-queue.php as a reference, with a comparator like this,

```
struct EdgeCompare
{
    bool operator()(const Edge &e1, const Edge &e2) const
    {
        return e1.weight < e2.weight;
    }
}

std::priority_queue<Edge, std::vector<Edge>, EdgeCompare> queue;
```

However, I then realized that `std::priority_queue` does not provide an iterator. This is a feature that I'd really like to have, so I decided to switch to a `boost::heap::priority_queue`. I know  that the `boost::heap::priority_queue` has a constructor that will set a custom comparator. However, I can't find any examples that explain how best to pass the function. I obviously can't use the same syntax that I used for the `std::priority_queue`.

I tried

```
EdgeCompare comparator;
boost::heap::priority_queue<Edge> queue2(comparator.operator);
```

But I get an error that tells me to specify an operator.

I also tried renaming the function, but then I get an error telling me that a pointer to a function can only be used to call the function.

What is the correct way to declare and pass the comparator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the option interface is somewhat under-documented.  You specify options like this:

```
boost::heap::priority_queue<Edge, boost::heap::compare<EdgeCompare>>
```