# Creating std::priority queue of std::pair of customized class

Tags: c++, priority-queue

(Previously referred) [STL Priority Queue on custom class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541560/stl-priority-queue-on-custom-class)

It may sound unnecessarily complex, but I'm trying to create a std::pair of a customized class and a 2D array of `enum availability` type.
Here is a declaration of the queue:

```
std::priority_queue < std::pair<Panel_string, availability**>*, std::vector<std::pair<Panel_string, availability**>*>, compareString > queue_string;
```

and here is a comparing function for the queue (each pair will be ordered according to its weight):

```
struct compareString {
bool operator() (const std::pair<Panel_string, availability**>* left, const std::pair<Panel_string, availability**>* right) const {
    return left->first->weight > right->first->weight;
}
};
```

I referred to the link above for the syntax of this.

However, I cannot compile it because there are only two errors detected in the compareString struct. In Visual Studio, two red line shows up in "left" and "right" (line 3 of the `struct compareString`), both alerting:

`IntelliSense: expression must have pointer type`.

If you're the expert I'm looking for, please help me ):

Comment: That is not a queue of pairs. It is a queue of pointers. But why all the pointers anyway?

Comment: A double pointer (`availability**`) can be used like a 2D array but is semantically somewhat different, as there's no guarantee just from the type that all rows/columns are the same length (it could be a "jagged array"). A dynamic 2D array is probably better done with a single pointer (`availability*`) where you calculate the indices (something like `i * rows + j`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pair's first element isn't a pointer, so don't use `->`.

```
return left->first.weight > right->first.weight;
```

`->` is for use in expressions that must have pointer type (or evaluate to instances of things that overload `operator->`.)

Comment: Yup, found it right after posting it (couldn't find it for last 2 hours). Sorry for bothering with such a simple mistakes...